# Telnet:connect to local ip in an extern network

Tags: command-prompt, telnet, putty

I need to start a telnet connection to an server that is on an extern netwerk.
the local ip is 192.168.2.1.
I can acces it outside the network with 81.82.x.x:3389. The ip listens to the port 9800 for telnet

I use the following command in cmd:

```
putty.exe -telnet 81.82.x.x:3389 9800
```

A new window open with the title 81.82.x.x - putty and an empty black screen. I can typ in it but it does'nt do anything. After a few seconds it close automaticly.

Am I doing something wrong / shouldn't I get a question for my username and password?

EDIT:

I have a remote network 81.82.x.x. 
The network runs a SSH server on the port 9800. 
In the network there is a mailserver, webserver, ...

the webserver has a local ip 192.168.0.1 and use port 3389

the mailserver has a local ip 192.168.0.2 and use port 3390

I want to execute the telnet command on the webserver/mailserver/...

Comment: If the service listens at port 9800 then you should connect to port 9800. You try to connect to port 3389, and whatever listens at that port didn't expect a telnet connection apparently.

Comment: when i try putty.exe -telnet 81.82.x.x 9800
I get the screen showing "SSH-2.0-OppenSSH_4.5p1" but still not asking for an username/password. But with this command I am connecting to the main server, not the local ip?

Comment: That's because you connect to a SSH server using telnet! You need to connect in SSH mode.

Comment: when i use the -ssh parameter it asks me for my login but when i type it in i get a fatalerror: No supported authentication methods avaible.

Comment: Have you asked the sys admin for the details of the connection? They may not have password auth enabled and you need to get an ssh key login by registering your public key on the target user.

Comment: I've re-read your question. Are you actually just trying to do port forwarding through a connection? i.e. your final destination on the target network is 192.168.2.1? it's not entirely clear what is running on where and what you're trying to connect to and from

Comment: I tried to rewrite my question...

Answer (score 1):

You appear to mention 2 ports, 3389 and 9800, it won't be listening on both.

For a telnet connection you can also use:

```
putty.exe telnet://host[:port]
```

so check which port it is actually listening on and try that.

Have you also got netcat installed? If so, you can test that the port is alive with:

```
nc -v host port
```

which will show a "succeeded" message if the port is available, so you'll know whether it's 3389 or 9800. As you're using windows, you may need to install cygwin to get a netcat client, or search for "netcat windows client" and if you trust it, download and install it.

**EDIT**

After your comments in the question, it appears the machine you're connecting to has an SSH server (Secure Shell) running on port 9800.

If this is the case, and that is the machine you wish to connect to, then use SSH to connect, not telnet. In general you should try and avoid telnet at all costs as it isn't secure, all communications between you and the server are un-encrypted and easily sniffed.

I think you need to read up on the differences between telnet and ssh, they are both ways of connecting to a remote machine, but ssh is secure, and telnet is not.

If you have the ssh user and password for the target server, then just use:

```
putty.exe user@host:port
```

Is there a reason you're trying to connect to telnet specifically? If not, then don't use it. Avoid it like the plague, and use SSH.

**EDIT 2**

You have added that you have an SSH server on 81.82.x.x:9800 and you want to connect to the telnet port of one of the servers behind that.

The way to do this is port forwarding through the ssh server.

Normally you would do this on command line with:

```
ssh -L10001:192.168.2.1:3389 -p 9800 user@81.82.x.x -Nfx
```

This will create a port on your local machine (port 10001 - you can choose any port > 1024) that connects through the ssh server at 81.82.x.x. It will connect to the ssh server using port 9800, and then the local tunnel will be established that forwards traffic to 192.168.2.1:3389.

The "Nfx" bit just doesn't create a shell, and doesn't forward X traffic, and if there's a password needed will wait for that to complete before returning.

You should then be able to telnet into your localmachine on port 10001 and get a telnet prompt for the target machine.

This assumes that the information you've given is correct and that:

1. SSH server: 81.82.x.x port: 9800
2. Telnet server: 192.168.2.1 port: 3389
3. You have the username and password on the SSH server
4. You have the username and password for the telnet server

Note, there is nothing to do with telnet with the tunnel. If the final port (3389) is being listened to by an SSH server, then your final part is to use "ssh user@localhost:10001" instead of telnet.

For putty, you can create tunnels through it's GUI interface [(see this article with pictures)](http://howto.ccs.neu.edu/howto/windows/ssh-port-tunneling-with-putty/), but I've always had more luck using cygwin and installing ssh so you can do everything on command line.

However, you said in your comments that you were getting "No supported authentication methods available" which suggests to me that the ssh server isn't allowing you to use passwords to connect. They may offer secure keys access, but you'll have to ask them to install your public key on the ssh server.

Comment: 3389 gets me to the local ip (the one i need) and 9800 is for telnet

Comment: I think you're confused by telnet and ssh, i'll update my answer

Comment: i have updated my question. I have been giving the task to start with telnet. At a later stage I will need to implement an SSH Tunnel

Comment: If the only connection point is an ssh port, you have to use that right away. I'll update my answer again

Comment: I can also open the webserver with 81.82.x.x:3389 with RDP (if that is what you mean with a connection point?)